# Why is this paraboloid not the correct shape?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d, surface

I'm trying to create a circular paraboloid (opening downward) with **pyplot** to approximate some points but I fear I'm missing perhaps something basic because the shape doesn't look right.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# here is a function to calculate the z for a (x,y) pair
def get_z(x,y,width,height):
    # opens downward
    c = - float(height)
    # circular so same width in both directions
    x2 = (x ** 2) / float(width) 
    y2 = (y ** 2) / float(width) 

    z = (x2+y2) / c

    return(z)  

# and here a function that does the plotting based on the xs and the ys
def plot_par(axes,xs,ys,zero_x=0,zero_y=0,width=1,height=100):

    zs = np.array([])

    for x in xs:
        for y in ys:
            # need to subtract the zero to center the surface
            zs=np.append(zs,get_z(x-zero_x,y-zero_y,width,height))

    Z = zs.reshape(len(xs),len(ys))

    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Here is an example. I've rotated the axes all I could but still I couldn't see the paraboloid; it looks like one of the axes (`carga_final`) is yielding constant values:

[image]

**Does anybody see anything obviously wrong here** and/or how I could fix it? I've tried to subtract the middle value (maximum + minimum / 2), as you can see in the image, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, the problem is because your x and y axes are of different length.

For example, using the following line (`x = 0-100, y = 0-500`) which seems to match your axes limits, you get a slightly curved surface in the y direction:

```
plot_par(ax,np.arange(0,100,1),np.arange(0,500,5),zero_x=50, zero_y=250)
```

[image]

But, if your `x` and `y` ranges are the same, it looks better:

```
plot_par(ax,np.arange(0,100,1),np.arange(0,100,1),zero_x=50, zero_y=50)
```

[image]

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for explaining.